# Custom tag to set a variable in Django template. Emptying the value out of context?

Tags: django, variables, django-templates, custom-tag

In my Django Template I want to set a variable, to use in a  html tag.
But, when I'm out the for loop, the variable is empty :(

```py
{% load custom_template_tag %}

<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for a_status in status %}
        {% for r in all_status_ressources %}
            {% if a_ressource.id == r.0 and a_status.name == r.1 %}
                {% setvar "selected" as selected_status %}
                id ressource : {{ r.0 }}, name status : {{ r.1 }} -> [{{ selected_status }}]<br>
            {% endif %}
                selected_status : "{{ selected_status }}"
        {% endfor %}
        end loop ---------> selected_status : "{{ selected_status }}"
        <option value="{{ a_status.id }}" selected="{{ selected_status }}">{{ a_status.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The custom tag itself :

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def setvar(val=None):
    return val
```

And, now the debug trace :

```
selected_status : ""

id ressource : 2, name status : "my personnal status" -> [selected]

selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"
selected_status : "selected"

end loop ---------> selected_status : ""
```

So, when I'm out of the for loop, the varible is not set to be used in the  html tag.

Comment: Why are you writing your own tag to do this, why not use `{% with <var>=<val> %}`?

Comment: How can I do with "with" ?. It's in a block, and in my code, there's aleardy blocks like  "loop", "if", etc.

Comment: You face this problem because you don't pass data in a proper format to your template from your view. Your view should provide your data in such a manner that the template can render it easily.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat : I agree :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `{% with <var>=<val> %}` tag:

Something like:

**template.html**

```html
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  {% for a_status in status %}
    {% for r in all_status_ressources %}
      {% if a_ressource.id == r.0 and a_status.name == r.1 %}
        {% with selected_status="selected" %}
          id ressource : {{ r.0 }}, name status : {{ r.1 }} -> [{{selected_status }}]<br>
        {% endwith %}
      {% endif %}
      selected_status : "{{ selected_status }}"
    {% endfor %}
    end loop ---------> selected_status : "{{ selected_status }}"
    <option value="{{ a_status.id }}" selected="{{ selected_status }}">{{a_status.name }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: So, after the {% endwith %} tag, the variable is not set. In my example, I can't retreive the value :(

Comment: But, for now, in my first message, I don't understand why the value, after the loop, is empty. Any idea please ?. Thanks

Comment: This is likely not a coding error but a logic error. What should the value of `selected_status` be outside of the if statement?